# Add icons before jQuery range slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I add font awesome or image before and after the range slider?
Like I did for text values:[image]

I try to do like this and it is working for output values

```
$('#wo').html('<i class="fa fa-child" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + ui.value + '<i class="fa fa-child" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
```

So here is my slider code

```
$(function () {
  $(weight).slider({
    animate: "slow",
    max: 250,
    mix: 75,
    step: 25,
    range: 'min',
    change: function( event, ui ) {
      $('#wo').html('<i class="fa fa-child" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + ui.value + '<i class="fa fa-child" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
      $('.ui-slider-handle:eq(0)').html('<span class="price-handle value">' + ui.value +  '</span>') ;
      showMiles();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Could you provide link to the plugin you are using?

Comment: I use jQuery and jQuery Ul  only, no plugins

Comment: Have your tried using **[create option with custom handle](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#custom-handle)**?

Comment: can you please add your html code as well.